# How to set div background image in MFMailComposeViewController html string

Tags: ios, css

I need to customize MFMailComposeViewController，required a text view in messageBody,so I wrote this:

```
 [mailController setMessageBody:@"<div style = \"background-image:url(./img_email_input.png); padding:10px\">Hi , <br/>  This is my new latest designed green card.</div>" isHTML:YES];
```

but the background image did not display,don't know why.

Through setting up boder property to display input box,but when I pressed the enter key,it would automatically create a same tag,the input box.                                          Here is my code:

```
[maiController setMessageBody:@"<div style=\"padding: 10px;margin: 0px;border-width: 1px;border-color: rgb(23, 23, 36);border-style: solid;border-radius: 0px;\">Hi,this is....</div>" isHTML:YES];
```